# Custom page for editing custom post type on frontend based on url

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, post-editor

I have created a custom post type nammed *job*. The users will have the posibility to create/read/update/delete their posts from frontend. I created a shortcode with a form for post creating, which is working fine, the *jobs* are adding and they can be accesed on the generic url *site_domain/jobs/job_title*.

Now I want to implement the *job* edit page which will be available on the previous url with */edit/* concatenated, like *site_domain/jobs/job_title/edit/*.

How can i create another page template/shortcode which will be used only if the user is accessing this endpoint ?

Comment: are you asking how to have `/edit` on the end and load a template? Or are you asking how to create the editor shortcode? The first probably needs a rewrite rule and a filter for the edit link if you want to redirect WP Admin to this new page as well

Comment: Yes, I want to have a /edit page on which the author of the job could edit it. I know how to create the editor, it is similar to job creating page ... I was thinking it would be more logical to edit the post by accesing the /edit page and in the backend I could scrap the post name and populate the fields with data from database

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom url structures with [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) for example the proposed structure in your question can be achieved with something like...

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^jobs/([^/]+)/edit/?$', 'index.php?post_type=jobs&name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} );
```

So now if you visited `https://example.com/jobs/job-title-example/edit/` you should see exactly the same as if you were to visit `https://example.com/jobs/job-title-example/` this is because we're telling WordPress to handle the request in a similar way by passing the `post_type` and `name` as query parameters. Essentially the same as visiting `https://example.com/?post_type=jobs&name=job-title-example`.

However, it might be a good idea to build the rewrite rule dynamically based off of the post type properties, something like...

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    
    if ( $post_type = get_post_type_object( 'job' ) ) {
        $rewrite = !empty( $post_type->rewrite ) && is_array( $post_type->rewrite ) ? $post_type->rewrite : [];
        $with_front = !empty( $rewrite[ 'with_front' ] ) ? $rewrite[ 'with_front' ] : false;
        $slug = !empty( $rewrite[ 'slug' ] ) ? $rewrite[ 'slug' ] : null;
        $slug = $slug ?: $post_type->name;

        $front = '';

        if ( $with_front ) {
            $permalink_structure = get_option( 'permalink_structure' );
            $front = substr( $permalink_structure, 0, strpos( $permalink_structure, '%' ) );
        }

        $slug = $front ? '/' . $slug : $slug;

        add_rewrite_rule( '^' . $front . $slug . '/([^/]+)/edit/?$', 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type->name . '&name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    }

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

So now if you change your `jobs` post type rewrite properties the rewrite rule above will adapt automatically.

Always remember to [flush your rewrite rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) if making any changes.

I would also concider adding a custom query var to use in templates, like so...

```php
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'frontend_editor';
    return $vars;
} );
```

And add to your rewrite rule with `&frontend_editor=1` like so...

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    
    if ( $post_type = get_post_type_object( 'job' ) ) {
        $rewrite = !empty( $post_type->rewrite ) && is_array( $post_type->rewrite ) ? $post_type->rewrite : [];
        $with_front = !empty( $rewrite[ 'with_front' ] ) ? $rewrite[ 'with_front' ] : false;
        $slug = !empty( $rewrite[ 'slug' ] ) ? $rewrite[ 'slug' ] : null;
        $slug = $slug ?: $post_type->name;

        $front = '';

        if ( $with_front ) {
            $permalink_structure = get_option( 'permalink_structure' );
            $front = substr( $permalink_structure, 0, strpos( $permalink_structure, '%' ) );
        }

        $slug = $front ? '/' . $slug : $slug;

        // We added `frontend_editor` parameter here.
        add_rewrite_rule( '^' . $front . $slug . '/([^/]+)/edit/?$', 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type->name . '&name=$matches[1]&frontend_editor=1', 'top' );
    }

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

This is essentially the same as visiting:

`https://example.com/jobs/job-title-example/?frontend_editor=1`

Or

`https://example.com/?post_type=jobs&name=job-title-example&frontend_editor=1`

In theory you should now be able to update your template to show the editor, for example...

**single-jobs.php**

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Check if user is authorised to edit current job -->
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && (int)get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_ID() ) === get_current_user_id() ): ?>

    <!-- Check for our edit parameter -->
    <?php if ( get_query_var( 'frontend_editor', false ) ): ?>

        <form action="">
            ...
        </form>

    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I think that should be enough to point you in the right direction. **Please note that none of the above code has been tested!**